# Responsive Image Sizing in React with Material-UI: How to Dynamically Adapt Images to Different Screen Sizes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm working on a React project using Material-UI, and I'm facing challenges in making the images within my component responsive across various screen sizes. Currently, I'm using the maxWidth property with a percentage value, but it is not like I want it to be, I'm wondering if there's a more dynamic and flexible approach.

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Box, Paper, useMediaQuery, useTheme, Typography, Grid, Container,
} from '@mui/material';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';

export const CarInfo: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    gilad: false,
    jason: false,
    antoine: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  const { gilad, jason } = state;

  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper
        elevation={3}
        sx={{
          p: 3,
          borderRadius: 2,
          textAlign: 'center',
          maxWidth: isMobile ? '100%' : 'xl',
          backgroundColor: 'grey !important',
        }}
      >
        <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom color={'white'}>
          Car Title
        </Typography>

        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <Typography variant="body1" align="left">
              Owner: {/* ... */}
            </Typography>

            {/* Additional car details: Fuel type, color, year, etc. */}

            <FormGroup>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={gilad} onChange={handleChange} name="gilad" size='small' />}
                label="Real Mileage"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={jason} onChange={handleChange} name="jason" size='small' />}
                label="First Owner"
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Grid>

          {/* Car Image */}
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
              alt="Car"
              style={{
                maxWidth: '100%',
                height: 'auto',
                margin: '0 auto',
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Typography variant="body1" align="left">
          License Details: {/* ... */}
        </Typography>

        <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>
            <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/533669/pexels-photo-533669.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
              alt="License"
              style={{
                maxWidth: '100%',
                height: 'auto',
                margin: '0 auto',
              }}
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} container style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: '-160px' }}>
              Document Link: {/* ... */}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CarInfo;
```

I want the images to resize more dynamically, adapting to the screen size while maintaining their aspect ratio. Is there a better way to achieve this with Material-UI or React in general? Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Context:

- I'm using Material-UI components, including Container, Box, and Grid.
- The images are currently styled with maxWidth: '100%' to achieve
  responsiveness, but it looks very amateur.

Comment: You can use aspectRatio css prop

Comment: I think it is not working in my case. :)

Comment: then look for objectFit

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping the images in a container that enforces a specific aspect ratio and uses object-fit for better control over the image rendering.

Here's an example of how you can modify your image styling:

```
// Import necessary components from Material-UI
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

// ...

<Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
  <Box
    sx={{
      position: 'relative',
      width: '100%',
      paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9 aspect ratio (modify as needed)
      overflow: 'hidden',
    }}
  >
    <img
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
      alt="Car"
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        objectFit: 'cover', // or 'contain' depending on your preference
      }}
    />
  </Box>
</Grid>
```

In this example, the Box component acts as a wrapper with a specified aspect ratio (16:9 in this case, modify as needed). The img element inside is absolutely positioned to cover the entire container while maintaining the specified aspect ratio using object-fit: cover.

Feel free to adjust the aspect ratio and styling properties to better suit your design requirements.